# How to pass the environment variables in command line and dynamically select the variables based on the url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am writing a test for rest api using mocha and Supertest.
I have more than one environment and some datas are different based on the environment. for an example , if i select the staging environment the datas are different compare to qa environment. specially i want to select the environment  in command line.

Please check the following test.

```
const request = require("supertest");
const express = require("express");
const expect = require("chai").expect;
const flush = require('flush-cache');


   var Token;
   var AddID;

   var stage ="http://www.stage-xyz.com";
   var qa = "http://www.qa-xyz.com";

var methods = {
  "login":"/login?",
   "address":"/address"    
}

var login = {
    "user":"abc@abc.com",
    "password":"xyz"   
}

var add = {
    "no": "121",
    "streetaddress": "covey street",
    "postalcode":"12345",
    "province":"NY"

}

beforeEach(function () {
     flush();
});

describe('POST /Authenticate', function() {

it('Retrieve Token', function(done) {
    request(qa).post(methods.login)
        .set('Content-Type','application/json')
        .send(login)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(err,res) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            Token = res.body.token;
            console.log(res.body);
            expect(res).to.have.property('status').equals(200);
            done();
        });
});

it('address', function(done) {
    request(qa).post(methods.perm)
        .set('Authentication',Token)
        .set('Content-Type','application/json')
        .send(add)
        .expect('Content-Type',/json/)
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(err,res) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            console.log(res.body);
            AddID = res.body.id;                
            expect(res).to.have.property('status').equals(200);
            expect(true).equals(Number.isInteger(AddID));
            done();
        });
});
```

});

however , eventually i want to give the input like below in a separate file called config.please help me to create a config module to pass an environment url and select the datas based on that.

```
var env = {

stage:{

    url:"http://www.stage-xyz.com"  

    login : {
        "user":"abc@abc.com",
        "password":"xyz",           
    }

    add : {
        "no": "121",
        "streetaddress": "covey street",
        "postalcode":"12345",
        "province":"NY"

    }

}

qa:{

    url:"http://www.qa-xyz.com""    

    login : {
        "user":"abc@abc.com",
        "password":"xyz"            
    }

    add : {
        "no": "121",
        "streetaddress": "covey street",
        "postalcode":"12345",
        "province":"NY"

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project, I use [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) to define configuration for my environments. It works really well.

My project folder:

```
- config
   - default.yaml
   - staging.yaml
   - qa.yaml
- test
```

You can use json format too.

To make it work, you must also change your source file to use the values defined in config

```
const config = require('config');

const user = config.get('login.user');
```

To running the test file with Mocha e.g. to target staging environment

```
$ NODE_ENV=staging mocha 'test/**/*test.js'
```

Hope it helps

Comment: would u able to post ur sample config file with sample test code ?. that will help me to understand. , also Is this similar to  dotenv "https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv"?

Comment: sorry for late reply, yes it is similar with dotenv.